# Mock a web server for ajax in IntelliJ environment

Tags: html, web-services, debugging, intellij-idea, mocking

IntelliJ can deploy HTML/JS code at `localhost:63342` on the fly. I can see how the frontend behaves immediately.

Now I have a web application.

```
http://localhost:8080/frontend
http://localhost:8080/backend
```

The frontend will fetch data from its backend. Now I cannot start a real backend at `localhost:63342`. How can mock some ajax response at `localhost:63342`. Is there any magic plugin of IntelliJ can help?

My current solution is put all ajax call in an Angular service module and replace it with a mocked service module. I believe there must be some better solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to mock up some endpoints for you to test with I would suggest you use [Mockjax](https://github.com/jakerella/jquery-mockjax). This will allow you to do exactly what you want and you won't have to run two separate apps to do so. I'm not familiar with IntelliJ, but Mockjax only has a dependency on jQuery and you should be able to easily set it up with any project that at least uses jQuery.

Comment: Alternatively, I can install a chrome extension "CORS Toggle" and redirect all requests from intellij debugging port to the original port. This works as well.